# I've got a project that won't open with VS2008, it's a Windows CE 5.X app - something with .net

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've got a project that won't open with VS2008, it's a Windows CE 5.X app - something with .net

I keep trying to open the project and it keeps saying it's not compatible with the installation.  I thought it might have been because i'm using VS2008 Standard and not Pro, but I read that Standard supports Windows CE. I was told that it might be because i'm running .net 3.5, and that I need to be on .net 2.0;  Does this mean I need to uninstall .net 3.5 from my PC in order for this to work? Or can I modify my environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2008 Standard does **not** support Windows CE Development. Where did you read that it does? Here you can read it does **not**: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en

Comment: I bought it from a software sales company, the guy said he was was a prior winCE developer; the differences between Standard and Pro are the fact that you can do external debugging with Pro.

Comment: The differences, my friend, I am sorry to tell you, are many more, download the document in the link I added and get to know the dozens of differences (one of them? no support for Windows CE, you can see that in page 19 and 20 of the PDF version

Comment: Sorry to read that someone told you such a lie, maybe you still can get a still get refund?

Comment: Ahh Okay.  Thank you so much! I think I can, hopefully!